# enable/disable location based notifications in ionic app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation, geofencing

I need to enable/disable the location based notifications based on user configuration.I am using corodva geofence plugin in my app.App is developed on ionic/cordova framework. Is it possible to do so using this plugin or is there any other way to do it?

Thanks in advance!